# Python 2.6 Module for GDAL 1.9.2, ImportError

Tags: python, gdal, linux

I work on an internal network (i.e. I can't get the latest 1.11 stuff) and have GDAL 1.9.2 set up on a Red Hat Linux Enterprise Server 6. My Linux box has python 2.6.6 however the Python binding I received in the swig directory appears to be for either Python 2.7.5 or Python 3.2.

I ran the setup.py but when I try to import OSGEO or GDAL I get this message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>:, line 1, in <module>
    File "osgeo/__init__.py", line 21 in <module>
        _gdal = swig_import_helper()
    File "osgeo/__init__.py", line 13, in swig_import_helper
        import _gdal
ImportError: No module named _gdal
```

Anyone got a link to the proper Python module or know of how I can get this to work. Got a lot of raster data that needs ripping apart.

Comment: You can try to compile osgeo yourself, it is not difficult [Installing GDAL python binding Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526517/installing-gdal-python-binding-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the gdal library to the PYTHONPATH environement variable. You can find some useful instructions for installing GDAL and python in this link

http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/

Questions similar to this have already answered in stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538725/cant-import-gdal-in-python
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500176/importerror-no-module-named-gdal